# STM32Cube command line programmer doesn't run the application after programing

Tags: stm32cubeide

STM32CubeProgrammer with ST_Link running on Windows (GUI) starts the application normally after programming. No problem there.

The command line version doesn't run the app. Even with the -s, -rst or -run options. The programming is done ok but the app got frozen after. Need a hardware reset to run.

This is the command line I'm using:

-c port=SWD freq=4000 -w ProgName.elf -V -s

or

-c port=SWD freq=4000 -w ProgName.elf -V -s 0x08000000

I discovered by accident that if I put some garbage at the end of the command line, the app runs!

For example:

-c port=SWD freq=4000 -w ProgName.elf -V -s -0

The programming is done and the app runs, but the Cube shows an error message at the end of the process due to the unrecognized garbage at the end of the command line.

What am I missing?

Have read the UM2237 and tried several commands, but no luck.

Edit: Tried ST-LINK_CLI.exe instead of STM32CubeProgrammer with success!
Had to use objcopy.exe to convert .elf to .s19 format accepted by ST_LINK_CLI.exe.

Used this command line:  -c SWD -P ProgName.s19 -rst

It seems with the STM32CubeProgrammer CLI the app starts, but without any IRQ enabled.

Answer (score 0):

The only part you missed is the parameter to be given to the `-s` option (can also be `--start`, or `-g`, or even `--go`).

As stated in the "*Figure 112. STM32CubeProgrammer: available commands*" from UM2237 ([download link](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjpg6mUha2CAxUDTKQEHWiTB4oQFnoECBAQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.st.com%2Fresource%2Fen%2Fuser_manual%2Fum2237-stm32cubeprogrammer-software-description-stmicroelectronics.pdf&usg=AOvVaw1CNQXxF1ef1d-yOhKnUOYA&opi=89978449)), Chapter 3, its expected parameter is the starting address at which the code should execute.

Regarding `-rst`, its purpose is to perform a system reset, unlike `-hardRst` which performs a hardware reset as you might have expected it.

Comment: Already tried that. Same result.

Comment: Can you specify your board, the CubeProg you have, as well as the ST Link version please ?

Comment: Last command -v result in:
"Error: Wrong verify command use: it must be performed just after write command or write 32-bit command"

Comment: ST-Link is a clone on a Blue Pill. Target is another Blue Pill.

Comment: Mmm, that's weird, it should work with the last version of CubeProgrammer. Well, anyway, here's what we use here : `-c port=SWD mode=UR -d app.bin 0x08000000 -V -rst` Maybe that'll work for you this way instead of using the `-s`. Off chance, is the result the same if you use a .bin rather than a .elf ?